# Trying to leverage 'shared scope' to configure ssl

Tags: karate

I'm trying to leverage Karates *shared scope* feature to configure ssl, like such:

```
@ignore
Feature: The 'Called' feature

  Background:
    * configure ssl = true
```

```
Feature: The 'Calling' feature

  Background:
    * callonce read('classpath:called.feature')
    * url baseUrl = '<some_base_url>'
    * def aPath = '<some_path'

  Scenario: Checking 'shared scope'
    Given path aPath
    When method GET
    Then status 200
```

This causes an `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for ...` error. However, if I add `* configure ssl = true` to the `'Calling'` feature, and forego the `callonce()`, it runs successfully.

Am I setting this up incorrectly, misunderstand shared scoped, or are certain `configure` settings not eligible for shared scope usage?

Comment: This sounds like a bug, so please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue